# Does AWS Network Load Balancer prevent DDoS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ddos

AWS ALB does routing based on content this means many common DDoS attacks like SYN floods and UDP reflection will be blocked.

On other hand, AWS NLB does not absorb any traffic hence my backend EC2s are open for any DDoS

So should I pay for AWS Shield Advanced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're looking at that sort of monthly spend (US$3K per month) you should have an AWS sales / technical person advising you.

Based on EIPs only being part of Shield Advanced, you probably won't get DDOS protection without the advanced product. However, you can get DDOS protection MUCH more cheaply from providers like CloudFlare.

Comment: Aws shield standard doesn’t cover DDoS for NLB. They added NLB support only in shield advanced  (via EIPs). They can’t provide support in standard because NLB doesn’t parse incoming traffic , it is just a pass through. It’s surprising that SSL offloading is supported though.

Comment: NLB supports Elastic IPs, and Shield Standard support Elastic IPs. Are you sure Shield won't support NLB with elastic IPs?

Comment: AWS Shield Standard includes monitoring for  Elastic Load Balancing load balancers (not NLB), Amazon CloudFront distributions, and Amazon Route 53. AWS Shield Advanced adds elastic IP to this list. With this setup I wonder who uses internet facing NLB for their apps.

Comment: Ok, I think you're right. I've updated my answer with another option.